# How to print to console.log from inside Angular.js inline-template's script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, debugging, console

I'm trying out the inline-template of Angular.js. **I would like to have a way to debug Angular objects by printing to the console whenever an html page is rendered.**

The inline-template puts html templates inside script tags. For example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/htmlpage.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- everything else here is html too -->
</script>
```

It's tricky because the stuff inside the script tags is not really JavaScript anymore. **So I don't know how to printing to the console inside the htmlpage.html with inline-template.**

I have tried but failed with nesting a script tag:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/htmlpage.html">
  <!-- html page template Angular stuff before is okay -->

  <script>console.log("this line DOESN'T SHOW UP anywhere");</script>

  <!-- html page template Angular stuff AFTERWARDS ALL FAIL-->
</script>
```

I also tried just throwing in a bare console.log, since it's inside a script tag.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/htmlpage.html">
  <!-- rest of html page template is okay -->

  console.log("this entire line gets output as text on the html page");

  <!-- rest of html page template is okay -->
</script>
```

but the entire line, `console.log("this entire line gets output as text on the html page");`, gets printed out to the html page, not the console!

Comment: You can add the text to the $scope in the .js file and then in the html add {{$scope.WhatEverTextYouWant}}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling some debugging function defined in the controller scope with `ng-init` in the template definition. See [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yoXdH4KsUy4vd6FugYC3?p=preview).

Let's say the template is defined by

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
  <div ng-init="log('In template: '+$index)">{{greet}} Melissa<div>
</script>
```

and you have a controller defined as

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.greetings = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Guten tag"];
    $scope.log = function(message) {
      $log.debug(message);
    }
  }]);
```

then

```
<ul ng-controller="myController">
  <li ng-repeat="greet in greetings">
    <div ng-include src="'myTemplate.html'"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

should print in the console

> In template: 0
>   In template: 1
>   In template: 2

The [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is called each time a template is instantiated. I just log some values available in the scope, like `$index` which is the index in the `ng-repeat` loop.

See [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yoXdH4KsUy4vd6FugYC3?p=preview).

Comment: Right so if this is a dynamic ng-repeat, would only the initial values be logged?

Answer (score 4):

Using the above answer, I found the following simpler.

> The easiest solution for me was to temporarily set `$scope.console = console` in my controller, letting the template have access to the `window.console` global variable and its associated functions as normal, through the `$scope` binding

Because the templates are tightly scoped, they do not have access to global and window variables, as a result `console.X()` is not available from the template. And, like you probably experienced, attempting to reference undefined values from within the template did not result in an error, just... nothing. (Cue tearing hair out trying to figure out why events aren't firing)